# Angular disable form validation when clicking Cancel in a dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular Material dialog with an input field and a Cancel button. The input field has a required validator.

When Cancel button is clicked, the input field is red just before the dialog closes itself. This does not look very well. Is there a chance to skip the validation of the form for this particular button?

The solution that I tried and does not work is trying to clear the validators. This does not work:

```
async onCancel() {
    this.form.clearValidators();
    this.form.setErrors(null); 
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();

    this.dialogRef.close(null);
}
```

The form code:

```
<div class="content" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="flex">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Email address</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="Email">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onInvite()" [disabled]="!form.valid" [class.spinner]="creating">Send invitation</button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a single input, you can set no validator on it, and on submit, you check if the input is required. If not, you set the error on it. You basically do the error management by hand. This way, it should do what you want.

Comment: @MGX. Thank you, I might use this solution in the end. I hoped there would be a different solution, to me this seems a common task.

Comment: This is because Angular material dialog manages the focus of the dialog (it focuses the input when you come into it). This is a good user experience, but in your case, it creates an unwanted feature. If you wish to change it, take a look at the documentation, it should explain how to cancel autofocus in the dialog.

Comment: What about using form reset?

Comment: Another idea is using updateOn property: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn For this scenario with 1 input looks like updateOn: 'submit' would work fine